# Doctrine:build Invalid schema element

Tags: symfony1, schema.yml

I use Symfony 1.4.2. When I use the command

```
doctrine:build --all
```

I get this error:

```
Invalid schema element named "term" at path "week->columns->relations"
```

Why does that happen?

Comment: You should update to symfony 1.4.15, you will get many bugfixes.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your class (schema.yml) is named "category" and you try to make a foreign alias in another class with the name "categories", which is not the guessed-by-symfony plural of category! Try with categorys, if it works use "foreignalias".